# Example integral question that contains more than 2 Integral Techniques

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus

For example, the integral 
$$ \int \sqrt{1-x^{2}} \: dx $$
Can be solved using trigonometric substitution and partial integration.
$$ \int \sqrt{1-x^{2}} \: dx = \int \cos^{2}(t) dt $$ with $x=\sin(t)$ substitution.
Then the latter can be solved using partial integration :
$$\int \cos^{2}(t) dt = \sin(t)\cos(t) + \int \sin^{2}(t) dt $$
and so on..

Another one, which is a good one, is

$$ \int \ln(x^{2} - 2x +5) \: dx$$
This can be solved using combination of *Partial integration*, then *subs $u=x-1$*, and then *Trig.subs* $u= 2 \tan(t)$. In that order.

---

My question is :
Is there one or two great sample problems such that we must use all these integration techniques : usual subs, partial integration, trig.subs, and also algebraic manipulation, in undergraduate level? **First year Calculus**

This is for an assignment, so that perhaps **one problem is enough to represent all techniques and material.**

I would appreciate the inputs, thanks.

Comment: Your definition of "all" could do with differentiation under the integral sign being added as well, for "completeness".

Comment: Isn´t $\int\sqrt{1-\sin^2(t)}dt=\int |cos(t)|dt$?

Comment: @Peter Nope its $\int |\cos t| \cos t dt$ :)

Comment: @King Tut .Ah Sure!

Comment: are you looking for some example?

Comment: I think you can combine some separate problems yourself ... It would surely benefit you...

Comment: @gimusi yeah, i have also edited the Q

Answer (score 2):

I will find the integral $\displaystyle{\int \frac{dx}{1 - x^2}}$ using five different methods. I hope this is the kind of thing you are after.

---

**Method 1** - Using a partial fraction decomposition

This is perhaps the easiest method of the five. Since
$$\frac{1}{1 - x^2} = \frac{1}{(1 - x)(1 + x)} = \frac{1}{2} \left [\frac{1}{1 - x} + \frac{1}{1 + x} \right ],$$
we have
$$\int \frac{dx}{1 - x^2} = \frac{1}{2} \int \left [\frac{1}{1 - x} + \frac{1}{1 + x} \right ] \, dx = \frac{1}{2} \ln \left |\frac{1 + x}{1 - x} \right | + C.$$

---

**Method 2** - Using a trigonometric substitution

This is also a relatively easy method to use.

Let $x = \sin \theta, dx = \cos \theta \, d\theta$. Thus
\begin{align*}
\int \frac{dx}{1 - x^2} &= \int \frac{\cos \theta}{1 - \sin^2 \theta} \, d\theta\\
&= \int \frac{\cos \theta}{\cos^2 \theta} \, d\theta\\
&= \int \sec \theta \, d\theta\\
&= \int \sec \theta \cdot \frac{\sec \theta + \tan \theta}{\sec \theta + \tan \theta} \, d\theta\\
&= \int \frac{\sec^2 \theta + \sec \theta \tan \theta}{\sec \theta + \tan \theta} \, d\theta\\
&= \ln |\sec \theta + \tan \theta| + C\\
&= \ln \left |\frac{1 + x}{\sqrt{1 - x^2}} \right | + C\\
&= \ln \sqrt{\frac{1 + x}{1 - x}} + C\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \ln \left |\frac{1 + x}{1 - x} \right | + C.
\end{align*}

---

**Method 3** - Using a hyperbolic substitution

Is very easy provided you are comfortable working with hyperbolic functions.

Let $x = \tanh u, dx = \text{sech}^2 u \, du$. Thus
\begin{align*}
\int \frac{dx}{1 - x^2} &= \int \frac{\text{sech}^2 u}{1 - \tanh^2 u} \, du\\
&= \int \frac{\text{sech}^2 u}{\text{sech}^2 u} \, du\\
&= \int du\\
&= u + C\\
&= \tanh^{-1} x + C\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \ln \left |\frac{1 + x}{1 - x} \right | + C,
\end{align*}
where in the last line the well-known [result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_hyperbolic_functions#Inverse_hyperbolic_tangent) for the inverse hyperbolic tangent function expressed in terms of the natural logarithmic function has been used.

---

**Method 4** - Using an algebraic substitution

If you are fortunate enough to see it, the integral can also be found using a [self-similar substitution](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/mathematical-gazette/article/10106-finding-some-integrals-using-an-interesting-selfsimilar-substitution/84F2FF4136DCE83996306691165EA679) of $u = \dfrac{1 - x}{1 + x}$.

Here we see that $x = \dfrac{1 - u}{1 + u}$ such that $dx = -\dfrac{2}{(1 + u)^2} \, du$. Under this substitution we see that
$$1 - x^2 = \frac{4u}{(1 + u)^2}.$$
Thus
\begin{align*}
\int \frac{dx}{1 - x^2} &= -\int \frac{(1 + u)^2}{4u} \cdot \frac{2}{(1 + u)^2} \, du\\
&= -\frac{1}{2} \int \frac{du}{u}\\
&= -\frac{1}{2} \ln |u| + C\\
&= -\frac{1}{2} \ln \left |\frac{1 - x}{1 + x} \right | + C\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \ln \left |\frac{1 + x}{1 - x} \right | + C.
\end{align*}

---

**Method 5** - Using integration by parts

This is by far the most circuitous method of them all.

Integrating by parts we have
\begin{align*}
\int \frac{dx}{1 - x^2} &= \frac{x}{1 - x^2} - 2 \int \frac{x^2}{(1 - x^2)^2} \, dx\\
&= \frac{x}{1 - x^2} + 2 \int \frac{(1 - x^2) - 1}{(1 - x^2)^2} \, dx\\
&= \frac{x}{1 - x^2} + 2 \int \frac{dx}{1 - x^2} - 2 \int \frac{dx}{(1 - x^2)^2}\\
\Rightarrow - \int \frac{dx}{1 - x^2} &= \frac{x}{1 - x^2} - 2 \int \frac{dx}{(1 - x^2)^2},
\end{align*}
or
$$\int \frac{dx}{1 - x^2} = -\frac{x}{1 - x^2} + 2 \int \frac{dx}{(1 - x^2)^2}.\tag1$$
To find the integral appearing on the right, let $x = \sin \theta, dx = \cos \theta \, d\theta$. Thus
\begin{align*}
\int \frac{dx}{(1 - x^2)^2} &= \int \frac{\cos \theta}{\cos^3 \theta} \, d\theta\\
&= \int \sec^3 \theta \, d\theta\\
&= \int \sec^2 \theta \cdot \sec \theta \, d\theta\\
&= \tan \theta \sec \theta - \int \sec \theta \tan^2 \theta \, d\theta \quad \text{(by parts)}\\
&= \tan \theta \sec \theta - \int \sec \theta (\sec^2 \theta - 1) \, d\theta\\
&= \tan \theta \sec \theta + \int \sec \theta \, d\theta - \int \sec^3 \theta \, d\theta. \quad (*)
\end{align*}
Since 
$$\int \sec \theta \, d\theta = \ln |\sec \theta + \tan \theta| + C \quad \text{(was found in Method 2)},$$
and as the integral for $\sec^3 \theta$ has reappeared, we have
\begin{align*}
\int \frac{dx}{(1 - x^2)^2} &= \frac{1}{2} \tan \theta \sec \theta + \frac{1}{2} \ln |\sec \theta + \tan \theta| + C\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \frac{x}{1 - x^2} + \frac{1}{4} \ln \left |\frac{1 + x}{1 - x} \right | + C.
\end{align*}
Thus (1) becomes
$$\int \frac{dx}{1 - x^2} = -\frac{x}{1 - x^2} + \frac{x}{1 - x^2} + \frac{1}{2} \ln \left |\frac{1 + x}{1 - x} \right | + C = \frac{1}{2} \ln \left |\frac{1 + x}{1 - x} \right | + C,$$
as expected.

Comment: Thanks @omegadot . What i am looking is an integral problem that must be solved by combination of techniques.

Answer (score 1):

Famously, expressing $\int\sec^{n+2}x dx$ in terms of $\int\sec^{n}x dx$ requires parts and algebraic manipulation. So let's start with the challenge of integrating $\sec^3 x$ and make it harder, as per your request, as $\int\cos x\sec^3 \sin x dx$. And we can add a "usual" substitution, viz. the calculation $f(y):=\int_0^y x\cos (1+x^2)\sec^3 \sin (1+x^2) dx$. And now to add in a use of differentiation under the integral sign, we pose the problem $\int_0^\infty z e^{-zf(y)}dz$.

Comment: Thanks. i think it is still not in the scopeof firrst year Calculus..

Comment: @Ariel Why not?

Answer (score 1):

A basic integral by parts is

$$\int \log x \: dx=x\log x-\int 1 \,dx$$

and by substitution (by polar coordinates)

$$\int e^{x^2+y^2} \,dx\,dy$$

another basic integral by parts is

$$\int \arctan x \: dx=x\arctan x-\int \frac{x}{1+x^2} \,dx$$

Comment: Thanks. Polar coordinates is off first year Calculus in my case

Answer (score 0):

I found one, it is from a book.

$$ \int \ln(x^{2} - 2x +5) \: dx$$
This can be solved using combination of *Partial integration*, then *subs $u=x-1$*, and then *Trig.subs* $u= 2 \tan(t)$. In that order.

But i am still open for another answer. Thanks.